# Attachment Over 25 mb in the last 30 days

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I have over 34K mailbox in Exchange 2010 organization.  We are planning to move to Office 365, but we want to identified mailbox in the folder sent items that have attachments over 25 mb for the last 30 days.  Could you help me?

Thanks,

Julio

Answer (score 0):

Do this by using [instruction](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikehall/archive/2013/06/27/large-mail-item-script.aspx).

I think this is done by EWS.
The mailbox search can do this, I think, but I can't write the correct keywords.